# Why does assigning a new object to a PHP array value cause a ParseError?

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I'm trying to define a private static array (since I'm on PHP 5.4 and can't use constant arrays) in the following manner:

```
private static $regions = array(
  'NA'  => new Region('NA', 'North America'),
  'EUW' => new Region('EUW', 'Europe West'),
  // etc...
);
```

Unfortunately, this is causing a ParseError.  If I change the `new Region(...)` code to just be a string for testing purposes, there is no longer a parse error.  This seems to imply that I can't assign an object as a PHP array value, despite [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) stating that it's doable:

> The value can be of any type.

So what is the problem here?

Comment: You can't do that because the array is static and in the class definition you can't use dynamic values like objects or functions.

Comment: So then how do you do something like this?

Comment: One way is to have an 'init()' function that is called by your 'bootstrap'. or just call the init() function in the same file that defines the class after the class definition.

Comment: @MattHuggins Wrote a answer and explained a bit more hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that because the array is static and in the class definition you can't use dynamic values like objects or functions.

As an example what don't work!

(Here i used a function, but as i said you can't assign 'dynamic' values to a property in the class definition)

```
class A {

    private $basename = basename(__FILE__);

}
```

What would work for this is the following one, because we assign the value in the constructor.

```
class A {

    private $basename = "";

    public function __construct() {

        $this->basename = basename(__FILE__);

    }

}
```

Because think of that would be the first example possible, could be every object you create out of that class different! And a class definition is like a plan to build an object, but if you could use functions in a plan you could have every time a different plan to build the object, so that's how OOP works and it doesn't let you do that!

So your example doesn't work because of that, because you can't use an object in the class definition. And the solution for the example above doesn't work for your's neither, because the array is also static.

So you would have to make the array 'unstatic' and the assign the object to the array in the constructor like this:

```
class A {

    private $regions = array(
      'NA'  => "",
      'EUW' => ""
      // etc...
    );

    public function __construct() {

        $this->regions["NA"] = new B();
        $this->regions["EUW"] = new B();

    }

}
```

So for the end to give you something nice to read and from a official source see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

And a quote from:

> They (properties) are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Comment: Would it help to add some 'positive' ways that the OP could get their 'code' to work? Explaining why it doesn't work it obviously 'good'. What should they be doing from where that are now?

Comment: @RyanVincent Look at the last example, i did a example that works.

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting your 'static class variables'
 initialized is to run an 'init()' function, in which you can do whatever you like', to setup the internal 'static variables' in the class.

As you are dealing with a 'limitation' of the 'system'. Some variance from the 'rules' i think is allowed. The easiest way is to run an 'init() function after the class is declared.

Note: the 'rules' are that a 'file' declares a 'class' and that  a 'separate' file does 'actions' on the class. I think that, this usage used here, is 'sort of 'ok'. Hmm... there is no 'one true way'?

Think of it as dealing with a 'limitation' of 'class initialization'.

Imagine i want an initilized 'static' date class. Is just to show that you can do anything in the 'init()' function.

The class:

```
class A {

    /*
     *  What i want is a date and time object in this static variable
     */
    // private static $when = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s', '2014-04-01 11:59:00');

    // so i need to initialize it later...
    private static $when = null;

    // show the stored DateTime
    public static function showDateTime($format = \DATE_RFC850)
    {
        if (is_null(self::$when)) {
            return 'Is not set yet...';
        }
        else {
            return self::$when->format($format);
        }

    }

    public static function getWhen()
    {
        return self::$when;
    }

    public static function init($when = '2014-04-01 11:59:00')
    {
        self::$when = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $when);
    }
}

var_dump('Before Init: '. \A::showDateTime());

/*
 * now run the init()
 */
\A::init();

var_dump('After Init: '. \A::showDateTime());
```

Result:

```
string 'Before Init: Is not set yet...' (length=30)

string 'After Init: Tuesday, 01-Apr-14 11:59:00 BST' (length=43)
```